# Inheritance of non model, core class in Odoo/OpenERP

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

In Odoo, I want to modify the addons/web/session/OpenERPSession class without modifying the core code. Meaning I want to subclass this class from my module so that the system will use my version of the OpenERPSession class instead of the core class. And specifically I want to alter only a method's implementation, and I do so by overriding it:

```
class ExtendedSession(session.OpenERPSession):

    def model(self, model):
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        _logger.info('OVERRIDEN ==================== OpenERPSession.model')
        if self._db == False:
            raise session.SessionExpiredException("Session expired")
        return session.Model(self, model)
```

But unfortunately the 'OVERRIDEN ==================== OpenERPSession.model' statement is not print therefore the system does not call my implementation.

How can I instruct Odoo to use my implementation of the OpenERPSession?

Comment: Did you add web module as dependency for your module?

Comment: Yes I have. But odoo does not use my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering late...

For any non model class, you can inherit them by using full signature path of that class, for ex.

You can inherit `session.OpenERPSession` using the full path ...

```
class ExtendedSession(addons.web.sessions.OpenERPSession):

    def model(self, model):
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        _logger.info('OVERRIDEN ==================== OpenERPSession.model')
        if self._db == False:
            raise session.SessionExpiredException("Session expired")
        return session.Model(self, model)
```

Try this......